# Проблема с установкой пакета h2oEnsemble на R

Tags: r, package

Я пытаюсь установить пакет h2oEnsemble на R версии 3.2.3 для анализа ансамбля моделей. Установлен пакет H2O версии 3.10.0.8. При вводе следующих команд:

```
library(devtools) 
install_github("h2oai/h2o-3/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package")
```

выходит сообщение:

> Downloading GitHub repo h2oai/h2o-3@master from URL
>   https://api.github.com/repos/h2oai/h2o-3/zipball/master Installing
>   h2oEnsemble "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file
>   --no-environ --no-save  \   --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \   "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpi0Q2AV/devtools9583548338a/h2oai-h2o-3-a0a4bbc/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package"
>   \   --library="C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"
>   --install-tests   "C:\Program" ­Ҝ пү«пҜвбп ү­гваҜ­­Ҝ© Ё«Ё ү­Ҝи­Ҝ© Ө®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбÜ®«­пҜ¬®© Üа®Ҹа ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ü ӨҜв­л¬ д ©«®¬. Error: Command
>   failed (1)

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `"C:\Program" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или открытым файлом.` там написано

Comment: @Sanek Zhitnik, cпасибо за ответ. А из-за чего могла возникнуть эта ошибка?

Comment: Скорее всего установщик принял путь до места установки без ковычек.  Воспринял наличие пробела как конец пути, поэтому не смог найти ни программы такой, ни файла. Да и папки скорее всего у вас такой нет) Вы самостоятельно не указываете путь?

Comment: Нет. А где его нужно прописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему у Вас ошибка:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. Error: Command failed (1)

данная ошибка возникает из-за пробела директории **(C:\Program Files)** . Согласно документации,

```
If you want to be able to build packages from sources, we recommend that you choose an 
installation path not containing spaces.
```

Информация по данной ссылке : [How do I install R for Windows?](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f)

Попробуйте сменить установочную директорию, это должно сработать.

Comment: Оффициальный язык сайта - руский. Пожалуйста добавьте перевод

Comment: @cache now : sorry, don't know russian. :(

Comment: Кратенько: не ставьте R в папку, путь которой содержит пробелы.

Comment: @SanekZhitnik, большое спасибо. Переустановила R. Все работает :)